# Getting Video View data as an inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream, android-videoview

I am working on an application which plays hls streams from a server. I have used Video view for playing the stream. But now I need the stream data for some background processing. Is it possible to get the stream data which is currently playing in the video view as an inputstream??